# How to display TextView in center inside canvas?

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas

I have a `TextView` that I place inside a `canvas` using a `layout`.
first question I have is How to center it ? 
because every time i do `width/2` and `height /2` it gives it an offset.

And Secondly why is my `angleTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);` not working ?

here is what I'm doing to draw my `TextView` any suggestions ?

onDraw:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        if (pathsArray.size() == 0) { // initlizes the init
            init();
        }

        // draws the first circle
        canvas.drawCircle(width / 2f, height / 2f, OUTER_RING_DIAMETER, firstCirclePaint);

        //go through the array and paints the corisponding cells
        for (int i = 0; i < pathsArray.size(); i++) {

            if (pathsArray.get(i).state == 1) { // scanned
                canvas.drawPath(pathsArray.get(i), fillColorForSlicesNoHbs);
                canvas.drawPath(pathsArray.get(i), circleOutlinesPaint);

            } else if (pathsArray.get(i).state == 2) { // found hbs
                canvas.drawPath(pathsArray.get(i), fillColorForSlicesWithHbs);
                canvas.drawPath(pathsArray.get(i), circleOutlinesPaint);

            } else {
                canvas.drawPath(pathsArray.get(i), mainPaintForSlices);
                canvas.drawPath(pathsArray.get(i), circleOutlinesPaint);
            }
        }


        //paint the outer circles
        canvas.drawCircle(width / 2f, height / 2f, OUTER_RING_DIAMETER, outSideCirclePaint);

        canvas.drawCircle(width / 2f, height / 2f, (OUTER_RING_DIAMETER - (RINGS_STEP)), circleOutlinesPaint);

        canvas.drawCircle(width / 2f, height / 2f, (OUTER_RING_DIAMETER - (RINGS_STEP * 2)), circleOutlinesPaint);

        canvas.drawCircle(width / 2f, height / 2f, (OUTER_RING_DIAMETER - (RINGS_STEP * 3)), firstCirclePaint);


        canvas.drawPath(highlightedPath, highlitedCirclePaint);

        for (int i = 0; i < pathsArray.size(); i++) {

            if (pathsArray.get(i).elvation == highlightedPath.elvation) {

                if (pathsArray.get(i).state == 1) { // scanned
                    canvas.drawPath(pathsArray.get(i), fillColorForSlicesNoHbs);
                    canvas.drawPath(pathsArray.get(i), circleOutlinesPaint);

                } else if (pathsArray.get(i).state == 2) { // found hbs
                    canvas.drawPath(pathsArray.get(i), fillColorForSlicesWithHbs);
                    canvas.drawPath(pathsArray.get(i), circleOutlinesPaint);

                } else {
                    canvas.drawPath(pathsArray.get(i), circleOutlinesPaint);
                }

            }
        }


        //draws the dark opacity on top of everything else
        canvas.drawPath(lowlightedPathOuter, lowlitedCirclePaint);
        canvas.drawPath(lowlightedPathInner, lowlitedCirclePaint);


        // draw the needle
        // draw the circle of the current elevantion.
        alignmentSlice staticNeedle = getSlicesPaths(width / 2f, height / 2f, (OUTER_RING_DIAMETER - (RINGS_STEP * 3)), OUTER_RING_DIAMETER + 100, 0, 0.6f, 0);
        alignmentSlice mainNeedle = getSlicesPaths(width / 2f, height / 2f, (OUTER_RING_DIAMETER - (RINGS_STEP * 3)), OUTER_RING_DIAMETER + 100, needleAngle, 0.6f, 0);

        canvas.drawPath(staticNeedle, paintSecondaryNeedle);
        canvas.drawPath(mainNeedle, paintMainNeedle);


        //puts a text view
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());

        angleTextView = new TextView(getContext());
        angleTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        angleTextView.setTextSize(width/35);
        angleTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        angleTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        angleTextView.setText(angleText);

        layout.addView(angleTextView);

        layout.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        layout.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

        // To place the text view somewhere specific:
        canvas.translate((width/2)-(width/15), (height/2)-(height/27));


        layout.draw(canvas);

    }
```

Comment: What kind of offset? Have you tried `(width + textview.getMeasuredWidth())/2` and `(height + textview.getMeasuredHeight())/2` ?

Comment: yea i tried it, it reailly offsets it to the bottom right

Comment: you are creating a new `RelativeLayout` and calling its `addView` method inside `onDraw`??? do you know how often `onDraw` can be called?

Comment: that is the only way i read how to put a textview inside a canvas, do you have a better way ?

Comment: Dumb question - when you print the `textview.getX()` and `textview.getY()` - are they on the desired place (width/2 and height/2 of the canvas?)

Comment: see `android.text.Layout`

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use `gravity` you need to set it on the parent. In this case `layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)`. If you want to set it on the `textview` you have to use `layout params`.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

angleTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: what layoutparams should i import ? is it, LinearLayout.layoutparmas ? or RelativeLayout.layoutparmas ?

Comment: I'm actually not sure if it matters in this case, but I would use RelativeLayout so that it matches the parent.

Comment: it still didn't fixed it, still the same problme

Answer (score 2):

changed the `textview` to:

```
Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.alignementWhite));
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        textPaint.setTextSize(width/10);

        int xPos = (canvas.getWidth() / 2);
        int yPos = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent()) / 2)) ;

        canvas.drawText(angleText, xPos, yPos, textPaint);
```